# Как создать динамические табы в бутстрап?

Tags: bootstrap

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="index.php">Главная</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="view_aystopper.php?go=news">Новинки</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="view_aystopper.php?go=leaders">Лидеры продаж</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="view_aystopper.php?go=sale">Распродажа</a></li>
    <p align="right" id="block-basket"><img src="/images/cart-icon.png"><a href="cart.php?action=oneclick">Корзина пуста</a></p>
</ul>
```

Не получается создать динамические табы. При переходе по ссылкам ничего не происходит.

Создать нужно [вот такие менюшки](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacke%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bd=h), только вместо `id` элемента — ссылка.

Comment: `http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h` - создать нужно вот такие менюшки только вместо `id` элемента ссылка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аттрибут `data-toggle` это инструкция для JavaScript-компонентов Bootstrap. Скорее всего Вы забыли включить в страницу эту часть фреймворка:
`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
("3.3.5" нужно заменить на номер используемой Вами версии)